# SQL Server Inner Join Creating Duplicate Records

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables that I've create an inner join between and for some strange reason it's returning more records that I expected.

Table 1 has 6 records in it including 2 records of 'Version 1', 2 records of 'Version 2', and 2 records of 'Version 3'. Table 2 has 10 records in it including 10 records of 'Version 1'. If I do a inner join between them on the Version fields I would have thought I'd only get 2 records: Table 1 and Table 2 only match on 'Version 1' of which there are only 2 in Table 1.

However, the following query returns 20 records (if anything I could of understood 60 records if it's converting to cross join, which also would be wrong):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 T2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 on T2.VersionKey = T1.VersionKey
```

Can anyone help explain what's happening?

I have another set of tables that are VERY similar which are giving me the expect results and I can't see the difference here.

Here are the basic table structures and data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VersionKey] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VersionKey] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [Table1] (VersionKey)
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
GO

INSERT INTO [Table2] (VersionKey)
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION     
    SELECT 1
GO
```

Comment: Ok. Werid. Extra comment. I just did the above in a brand new database and it's turning out as I expected. But in my existing database it's still not correct.  Is there something I need to flush or refresh or ??

Comment: 20 rows is the expected and correct result for the data you have shown.

Comment: INNER JOIN is creating a 1-to-1 on your primary, which has 2 matches. So, 2 x 10 = 20. If you don't want duplicates, you may want to group them, select unique, etc.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make sense. I've just created a brand new database with the exact script above and it's returning 2 records.  That's as I expected as I thought inner join was supposed to only return records that match... not do a cross join on records from the primary table it matches.  Again, I have anoher table with VERY similar strucutre: Table 2 has 2160 records and Table 1 has 3. All three records from Table 1 match what is in Table 2. The results return 2160 - not some multple of it (like 3x2160)

Comment: @ptownbro That's because your setup script has a bug and isn't inserting 10 rows to table 2 at all.

Comment: Wow. You're right. I added the other 9 records and it's giving me 20 records again. Also tried this in MS access (my home base) and also giving me 20 records.  I'm really baffled here...I thought inner joins returned matched records (unless you do a left or right).

Comment: BUT. I still don't understand why my other tables don't do this.  I have a Fact table that has approx 2100 records in it which is inner joined with a dimension table with 3 records in it.  All 3 records from the dimension table are represented in the fact table.  The results only return the 2100 records. This works like I expected. It's not  returning some factor greater than 2100 like in my 20 record example.  Why is that???

Comment: @ptownbro presumably because the joining column in the three dimension records are different. You would only see this if you have duplicate records for a given joining key on both sides.

Comment: You are right! I just realized this myself late last night when I was thinking about it.  It was a 'duh' moment to say the least. I'm just used to using the primary key as my join which are always unique values and have not run into this very often. I looked at some old code and found that I in fact to account for the duplication by using DISTINCT. I must have forgotten. =) Losing my mind I guess. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup script has a bug.

```
INSERT INTO [Table2] (VersionKey)
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION      
    SELECT 1
```

That final `UNION` needs to be `UNION ALL` or you will remove duplicates and only insert 1 row not 10.

A fixed script and query results on SEDE is here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/478676/fixed-script

It returns 20 rows, this is expected and correct.

Logically each row in the left table is compared to every row in the right table. If the join predicate evaluates to true then the match is preserved.

If the inner join predicate is something that is always true, e.g `On 1=1` every row in the left ends up successfully matching every row on the right so you just end up with a cross join.

In your case both rows in Table1 with a VersionKey of 1 match 10 rows in Table2 so together they contribute 20 rows. The remaining rows in Table1 don't successfully join to anything and contribute 0 rows.

Comment: As I said above... this doesn't make sense. I've just created a brand new database with the exact script above and it's returning 2 records. So there has to be something else causing a different result in my current db. Also see my comment above to another reply.

Comment: I agree 100% with Martins excellent summation and I have been able to reproduce the outcomes you are seeing based on the sample data provided and with the change to table2 suggested  by Martin.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Martin above, but to clarify the answer for others following...

As eloquently explained above by others (thanks again for your help) the results are correct and, using my example, it should produce 20 records. However, here's the explanation as to why it's happening which was my original question.

The reason for the duplicate records is because the table you are joining to has duplicate records in the field you are joining on.

[image]

That solves the mystery for why I didn't see this in my other tables which contain the 2100 and 3 records respectively. There are no duplicates in the table with 3 records, hence, no duplicates in the final query results.

Why you normally may not see this is because you may typically be joining off the indexed primary key field like an ID field versus what I've done here. In those cases, since those records values will always likely be unique you'll never get duplicates.

Thanks again everyone for your help.

Here's my corrected code from above again with the bug fixed to reproduce the results.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VersionKey] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2] (
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VersionKey] [int] NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) 
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [Table1] (VersionKey)
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
GO

INSERT INTO [Table2] (VersionKey)
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
    SELECT 1
GO

SELECT * FROM TABLE2 T2 INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 on T2.VersionKey = T1.VersionKey
```